# How do I render multi texture with openGL ES one time?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I am currently writing a video player app for android. The idea was that I could draw multi textures in one same view. Now that I have four textures, I need to joint four textures. Each textures renders in different area in same view.
My vertex shader show as follows:

```
private static final String VERTEX_SHADER =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
        "uniform mat4 uTexMatrix;\n" +
        "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n" +
        "attribute vec4 aTextureCoord;\n" +
        "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        "    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n" +
        "    vTextureCoord = (uTexMatrix * aTextureCoord).xy;\n" +
        "}\n";

private static final String FRAGMENT_SHADER_2D =
        "precision highp float;\n" +
        "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
        "uniform sampler2D sTexture;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        "    gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
        "}\n";
```

My draw code as follows:

```
public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix, FloatBuffer vertexBuffer, int firstVertex,
                 int vertexCount, int coordsPerVertex, int vertexStride,
                 float[] texMatrix, FloatBuffer texBuffer, int textureId,
                 int texStride, int waterMarkTextureId) {
    GlUtil.checkGlError("draw start");

    // Select the program.
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramHandle);
    GlUtil.checkGlError("glUseProgram");

    // Set the texture.
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(mTextureTarget, textureId);

    if (mWaterEnabledLoc >= 0) {
        if (waterMarkTextureId != -1) {
            GLES20.glUniform1i(mWaterEnabledLoc, 1);
            GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE2);
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, waterMarkTextureId);
            GLES20.glUniform1i(mWaterTextureLoc, 2);
        } else {
            GLES20.glUniform1i(mWaterEnabledLoc, 0);
            GLES20.glUniform1i(mWaterTextureLoc, 0);
        }
    }

    // Copy the model / view / projection matrix over.
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixLoc, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
    GlUtil.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

    // Copy the texture transformation matrix over.
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muTexMatrixLoc, 1, false, texMatrix, 0);
    GlUtil.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

    // Enable the "aPosition" vertex attribute.
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionLoc);
    GlUtil.checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");

    // Connect vertexBuffer to "aPosition".
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionLoc, coordsPerVertex,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer);
    GlUtil.checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer");

    // Enable the "aTextureCoord" vertex attribute.
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureCoordLoc);
    GlUtil.checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");

    // Connect texBuffer to "aTextureCoord".
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureCoordLoc, 2,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, texStride, texBuffer);
    GlUtil.checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer");

    // Draw the rect.
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, firstVertex, vertexCount);
    GlUtil.checkGlError("glDrawArrays");

    // Done -- disable vertex array, texture, and program.
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(maPositionLoc);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(maTextureCoordLoc);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(mTextureTarget, 0);
    GLES20.glUseProgram(0);
}
```

Ideally, it turns out as follows:

```
___________________
|Texture1|Texture2|
|Texture3|Texture4|
___________________
```

I tried to draw four textures in four times, but it didn't work. I use different texMatrix and same mvpMatrix as GlUtil.IDENTITY_MATRIX for drawing each texture. But the result shows that only the last one texture rendered in the view. It turns out as follows:

```
___________________
|********|********|
|********|Texture4|
___________________
```

The * expresses as the GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE of Texture4.

I also tried to transform the mvpMatrix, and there will be four textures presented, but the orders is wrong as follows:

```
___________________
|Texture4|Texture3|
|Texture2|Texture1|
___________________
```

As for the rest areas are the GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE of each texture, it didn't work for transforming mvpMatrix again.

Is there better way for me to draw multi textures in one view? Looking forward for your answer sincerely.

Comment: `int textureId = mTextures[i];

mSurfaceTextures[i].getTransformMatrix(mTransform);
Matrix.scaleM(mTransform, 0, mTransform, 0, scale[i], scale[i], 0.0f);
Matrix.translateM(mTransform, 0, mTransform, 0, offsetX[i], offsetY[1], 0.0f);

mProgram.draw(GlUtil.IDENTITY_MATRIX, mRectDrawable.getVertexArray(), 0,
                mRectDrawable.getVertexCount(), mRectDrawable.getCoordsPerVertex(),
                mRectDrawable.getVertexStride(),
                texMatrix, mRectDrawable.getTexCoordArray(), textureId,
                mRectDrawable.getTexCoordStride(), waterMarkTextureId);`

Comment: "Anyway if you want to use this approach then you have to discard fragments or you have to use blending"- What does discard fragments means? Would you mind describing it in detail?

Comment: Thanks. I would try changed the shader code to input 4 textures, and draw them in one draw call.

Comment: *"I tried to draw four textures in four times, but it didn't work."* - How do you compute the `mvpMatrix` for the 4 tiles?

Comment: Similar like texMatrix, I transform the mvpMatrix with offsetX and offsetY.